# Item limits for a comboBox in PyQt4?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, raspberry-pi3

To qualify my level of experience, I am a beginner at Python and PyQt.

My question is; Is there a limit to how many items can be dynamically added to a comboBox?

The widget in question has a list of Countries in a comboBox and when it's activated, it dynamically adds items to a Cities comboBox.

When I attempt to add more than 10,000 items to the Cities comboBox, it kinda locks up. It will display the first city in the list, but the comboBox itself is not selectable, it doesn't 'drop down'.

However, after I select a Country 'that does not work', if a country with less than ~9000 items is selected, the list is still populated in the City comboBox and it is able to 'drop down'.

The most items I have been able to add, and have the City comboBox still 'drop down', is 8665.

The code I'm using to initialise the Country comboBox and update the City comboBox follows;

```
...

def __init__(self, parent=None):

    super(WeatherConfigDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    self.setupUi(self)

    self.location_manager = LocationsManager()

    self.set_countries()

    self.countryComboBox.activated[str].connect(
        self.on_country_combo_activated
    )

def set_countries(self):

    countries = self.location_manager.get_countries()

    self.countryComboBox.addItems(countries)

    self.on_country_combo_activated(countries[0])

def on_country_combo_activated(self, text):

    self.cityComboBox.clear()

    cities = self.location_manager.get_cities(text)

    print(len(cities))

    for city in cities:
        self.cityComboBox.addItem(city[1])
```

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Python 3.4.2 and PyQt4.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#maxCount-prop

Comment: @PYPL Thanks, it says; "By default, this property's value is derived from the highest signed integer available (typically 2147483647)", so it does answer the question, but doesn't solve the issue. I am setting no value for the maxCount.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I'm adding 15000 items to combobox object and it remains fully functional. This might be some kind of hardware limitation i guess ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it for me @PYPL. Appreciate it! I agree it is most likely a hardware problem. At least, that's how it seems. There is a lot of lag on the larger drop downs that do display. I decided to go with an auto complete on the city names. Makes more sense to do it that way.